# Latest skype version doesn't allow to select multiple messages at once

Tags: skype

I've updated Skype today and found that I can't select few messages at once as I used to do in all previous versions of Skype. Does anybody knows how to select few messages at once? Because for now I can select only one message that makes my life really hard.
For those who ask skype version, I can't find it. If I click at help button, browser is opened, and I don't see any information about skype version.

[image: Version of skype is not displayed]

Comment: "Latest" is relative to time and platform. Please post your platform and Skype version.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but latest skype that I've got doesn't show which version number it is. Actually I can't find this information. I've tried to find it but wasn't successful with this

Comment: [help->about](https://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/29000/29287/skype-13-700x440.png) or something like this